# Lining up <Div> tags inside if() echo statements

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to print out the files in a directory in php, and one to line up the text files in one list and jpg files in another(at the same horizontal height, side by side).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
    $files = scandir('uploads');
    foreach($files as $file){
        $extension = pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if($extension == 'txt') {
            echo'<div style="text-align:center; margin-left:-120px;"> <br><a href="uploads/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></div>';
        }
        if($extension == 'jpg') {
            echo'<div style="text-align:center; margin-right:-120px;"> <br><a href="uploads/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></div>';
        }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the following files in the directory:

```
test.txt hello.txt test.jpg hello.jpg
```

Which gives me the output of: (in the middle of the screen

```
          test.jpg

          hello.jpg

test.txt

hello.txt
```

But I want something as such (in the middle of the page), where .txt files come first.

```
          test.txt   test.jpg

          hello.txt  hello.jpg
```

I've tried adding a css element of `float:left;' and then adding that class to the div's but that doesn't fix the problem.

I also tried using: `display: inline-block;` to no avail

Comment: Do txt and jpg match always? Is the files number even?

Comment: Yeah I'm only testing .txt and .jpg at the moment. And no the amount of files isn't always even, if only text ones are in the folder everything works fine, if the other if statement executes this problem happens.

Comment: your question is not clear. If you want to output a certain format, sort your data first. e.g. make your data to be an array [ test.txt ,  test.jpg, hello.txt ,  hello.jpg] then loop it

Comment: Okay I can do that, but then how do I line it up properly gonna be two echo's and two if's again, and boom same problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="files/hello.txt">Hello.txt</a></li>
  <li><a href="files/test.txt">Test.txt</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="files/hello.txt">Hello.jpg</a></li>
  <li><a href="files/test.txt">Test.jpg</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's a revised edition of your PHP-code, try that together with the CSS provided in the example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        div {
  text-align: center;
box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $filetypes = ['txt','jpg']; //with the following code you'll be able to add other fileextensions as you need them
    foreach ($filetypes as $ext) {
     $files = glob('uploads/*.'.$ext.'');
     echo '<div><ul>';
       foreach($files as $file){
            echo'<li><a href="'.$file.'">'.(explode('/',$file)[1]).'</a></li>';
       }
     echo '</ul></div>';
     }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, this is showing how the divs should match up, and what CSS you should use. Also including proper use of `<ul>` inside the divs. The files doesn't matter, I just put regular filenames in there instead of the PHP-code.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how I would copy this into my code then.As in I'll copy the css into the style tags, what am I soposed to replace in the echo statements?

Comment: the line: href="files/hello.txt" and the rest of it won't work unless I know the file names already, hence my php code.

Comment: Actually, it would take a bit of a code-change. I just realised that you actually output a `<div>` for every file you go through. You will have to run the foreach twice for the current setup you have. You'll need to start the `<div><ul>` outside the loop, and create the `<li>`s inside the loop for each of the filetypes.

Comment: You do understand that the HTML-code is NOT meant to be a direct copy, right, but how the end result should look when you iterate through the files. I know that the href=-part won't work for you, the point was to show you need TWO `<div>` with ONE `<ul>` in each of them, containing the file-lists for each extension.

Comment: Im a bit new to webdev, but I get that. I just don't understand through my foreach loop, would I have to replace the filename part with the $file variable when using echo?

Comment: I updated the code with a replacement PHP-code that should do what you want, with less code and better semantics for the HTML. Using that in the file you had above, with the CSS I gave you, should work.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to output anything on the screen. Adding a backslash to the glob outputs stuff with the file folder in question, and puts both txt and jpg files on the same row. Any ideas?

Comment: Still seems to print out the file directory name then the file (txt) and (jpg) all on the same column(not row, I made a typo last time)

Comment: Okay... I made a now tested and 100% working version - you could put in a little effort yourself, you know - the code did output the folder name, that took about 2seconds to fix. Look at the last code-entry in the answer above now. It outputs two columns, filename only, side by side.

Comment: I just don't know how to approach such problems even with google results, where most of them don't help my problem, it's so specific with what one is doing, it's pretty hard for a begginer.

Comment: For that particular problem, you output a string (the foldername/filename), and that string is being divided by the `/`- hence you look for a way to get the last part of the string, which is what I did above. Granted, it's a bit hackish, since it won't work if there are more folders, subfolders and such - for that you would have to do something like this instead: `array_reverse(explode('/',$file))[0]` which would split it the same way, reverse the array, so that the filename is always first, and then give you that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output a certain format, sort your data first. e.g. make your data to be an array [ test.txt , test.jpg, hello.txt , hello.jpg] then loop it like this:

```
foreach($data as $key=>$val){
    echo $val;
    if($key%2==0) echo '    ';//here is xx.txt, so you can write your css to make it in the beginning of line
    else echo "\n";// here is xx.jpg, make it clear right or append it a <br>
}
```